# Are these expressions equivalent?

Tags: notation, discrete-mathematics

5x = 0 (mod 6)
5x ≡ 0 (mod 6)
5x(mod 6) = 0 (mod6)
5x mod 6 = 0 mod 6

??

Sorry, it's really confusing and there are nothing about it in my lecture notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. These are several ways to express exactly the same thing. Namely, that $6$ divides $5x$.

Comment: Though I mus say that $5x\equiv 0\pmod 6$ is by far to be prefered.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand how 5x=0mod6 is equal to 5x ≡ 0 (mod 6)

Comment: *Imagine* the implicit brackets and implicit third horizontal line above the 2 others.

Comment: It's just different notation. Expressed in words, it's: "$5x$ is equivalent to $0$, *modulo* $6$."